# Scraping amazon with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm currently working on some personal projects and I just had the idea to do some amazon scraping so I can get the products details like the name and price.

I found that the most consistent view that used the same id's for product name and price was the mobile view so that's why I'm using it.

The problem is that I can't get the price.

I've done the same exactly query selector for the name (that works) in the price but with no success.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MUAGZ49';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 360, height: 640 });
  await page.goto(url);

  let producData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let productDetails = [];

    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#a-page');

    elements.forEach(element => {
      let detailsJson = {};

      try {
        detailsJson.name = element.querySelector('h1#title').innerText;
        detailsJson.price = element.querySelector('#newBuyBoxPrice').innerText;
      } catch (exception) {}

      productDetails.push(detailsJson);
    });

    return productDetails;
  });

  console.dir(producData);
})();
```

I should get the name and the price in the console.dir but right now I only get

```
[ { name: 'Nintendo Switch – Neon Red and Neon Blue Joy-Con ' } ]
```

Comment: Since that id is only visible in the mobile view you should emulate a mobile device (using the _page.emulate()_ method). See here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.6.2/docs/api.md#pageemulateoptions

Comment: I'm already doing it with the width and height of puppeteer, the name of the product with the id of "title" only appears on mobile but the price is kinda being blocked by amazon. edit: just didn't it and still doesn't work I added `isMobile: true` to the setViewport options

Comment: you were right, but due to my location the #newBuyBoxPrice didn't exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just setting the viewports height and weight is not enough to fully simulate a mobile browser. Right now the page assumes that you just have a very small browser window.

The easiest way to simulate a mobile device is by using the the function [`page.emulate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pageemulateoptions) and the default [DeviceDesriptors](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/5e21ba3cbbe455317158e6a4fc5af2808abd45df/lib/DeviceDescriptors.js), which contain information about a large number of mobile devices.

**Quote from the docs for `page.emulate`:**

> Emulates given device metrics and user agent. This method is a shortcut for calling two methods:
>
> - [page.setUserAgent(userAgent)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagesetuseragentuseragent)
> - [page.setViewport(viewport)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagesetviewportviewport)
>
> To aid emulation, puppeteer provides a list of device descriptors which can be obtained via the `require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors')` command. [...]

---

**Example**

Here is an example on how to simulate an iPhone when visiting the page.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');
const iPhone = devices['iPhone 6'];

const url = '...';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto(url);

  // Simlified page.evaluate
  let producData = await page.evaluate(() => ({
    name: document.querySelector('#a-page h1#title').innerText,
    price: document.querySelector('#a-page #newBuyBoxPrice').innerText
  }));

  console.dir(producData);
})();
```

I also simplified your `page.evaluate` a little, but you can of course also use your original code after the `page.goto`. This returned the name and the price of the product for me.

Comment: I just tried this and with the simplified productData I get `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`, modified with my same code I still just get `[ { name: 'Nintendo Switch – Neon Red and Neon Blue Joy-Con' } ]` which is just the name and the price seems to be blank.

Comment: I just figured it out, in my location amazon doesn't ship so there was no #newBuyBoxPrice. I changed the selector and now it works. Do you have any idea how to get set the geolocation?

Comment: @AlexeiRodriguez You can set geolocation via [`page.setGeolocation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagesetgeolocationoptions), but Amazon might also use your IP address to estimate your location.